# Video size in MB

Tags: iphone, html

What is a standard file size in MB for video on iPhone?

It will be a local storage on the app as it is Hybrid app (HTML, JS and CSS3).

Will use six videos. All on average one minute clips.

(NOT the width and height size)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard limitation on Video size by Apple, you just need to make sure Your ipa size must be less than or equat to 2 GB.

As per the  Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/iTunesConnect_Guide.pdf):

**iOS Application size tips**

- Apps can be as large as 2GB, but be aware of download times.
- Make efforts to minimize file size.
- Remember there is a 500MB limit for Over the Air downloads.

In your case, you have 6 local videos with the average 1 minute time, Not to worry! Just make sure total videos size is less than 2 GB.

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated. I'm aware that the overall size limit is 2GB.